# Adobe AIR SharedObject - Android/iOS - On update not found

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

As the title states, my user's on iOS and Android are reporting their save data has been deleted when I push an update to the respected storefronts. The game saves and restores data properly on application load and exit. I have not changed any save information locations or package names... Just mere bug fixes, build, push.

Any clarification would be helpful, or proposed redundant data backup scheme's I should pursue to ensure the end-user experience is from henceforth not affected negatively. I would also like to understand better how I can test this as a release package is not allowed to update a market installed application.

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("storage"); 
var u:User;
if(so.data != null){
    u = so.data.user;
}

trace("Loading application...");

if(u != null){
    trace("LOADING SAVE DATA");
    user = u;
}else{
    trace("NO SAVE DATA EXISTS");
    user = new User();
}
```

Comment: ShareObjects are not meant to be long-term persistent storage.  They are like browser cookies.  While I don't have enough experience with using them on mobile to know for sure, my guess is when you update your app, it's like clearing the cache where those cookies live.

Comment: It is my understanding that they are not intended to be used as a fill in for Cookies, as they are very useful in the serialization of Objects, for instance a User object that contains top scores.

Here are two Adobe staff responses on the issue: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5157157

Take note they do not mention against using a SharedObject for such a task.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose with AIR it would be different than with flash player where the user can choose to wipe all data, or not allow shared objects to begin with.  It's not a frontier I've explored much yet on AIR.  SharedObjects are very easy/convenient though for serialized storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the cause of this issue and it seems that Adobe has identified and fixed the issue as well (as of AIR 3.5). https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3347676

SharedObjects are stored within a directory named according to the SWF used by your application, so if your application is running off "myApp.swf" the SharedObject will be stored in a directory "myApp". If you change the name of this SWF (i.e. the corresponding XML build sheet configuration file for your AIR project) any subsequent builds will store their SharedObjects in a new location.

The issue described in this bug was specifically denoted for iOS, wherein the application was not storing the SharedObject in the corresponding SWF location as described above but in a separate location denoted by the "filename" attribute in your project's XML build sheet.

I have also discovered that Adobe does indeed condone the use of a SharedObject for persistent storage on a mobile platform.

I have developed a simple backup for future version save redundancy in case future updates fail to persist the SharedObject.

```
/** the last timestamp a deep save was completed */
private var mLastSave:Number = -1;


/**
 * save the state of the globals object and all of its
 * sub objects.
 * @warning
 * all objects must implement variables in a "public" state.
 * Private variables are not saved within the persistance manager
 */
public function save():void{
    var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("storage");
    so.data.user = user;
    so.flush();
    saveDeep();
}


/**
 * Save the SharedObject to denoted mobile applicationStorageDirectory.
 */ 
public function saveDeep():void{
    // save on first application save or after
    // every 5 minutes
    if(mLastSave == -1 || mLastSave < getTime() + 300000){
        mLastSave = getTime();

        var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("userSave");
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
        fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba.writeObject(user);
        fileStream.writeBytes(ba);
        fileStream.close();
    }   
}


/**
 * Load the application from the SharedObject be default
 * if the SharedObject DNE attempt to load from the 
 * applicationStorageDirectory, if neither exist
 * create new User object
 */ 
public function load():void{

    registerClassAlias("user", User);

    // Create/read a shared-object named "userData"
    var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("storage"); 
    var u:User;
    if(so.data != null){
        u = so.data.user;
    }

    trace("Loading application...");

    if(u != null){
        trace("LOADING SAVE DATA");
        user = u;
    }else{
        trace("NO SAVE DATA EXISTS");
        var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("userSave");
        if(file.exists){
            trace("Found userSave backup -attempting to load");
            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            fileStream.readBytes(ba);
            fileStream.close();
            try{
                user = (ba.readObject() as User);
            }catch( e : EOFError ){
                trace("SharedObject did not exist, attempted userSave load, failed");
            }
        }else{          
            user = new User();
            trace("created New user...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the "userSave" directory name? I'm facing a similar issue and I couldn't find a persistent directory after app update.

Comment: I have since ditched SharedObjects. They are really fantastic for persisting large classes of data, but I found myself mistreating the system and relying too heavily on data persistence when I didn't need it in the first place. Also from a readability standpoint having a bunch of public variables in a class generated some difficult debugging situations. I have moved to XML for persisting data and avoid SO's now. After a few application updates on Android and iOS many of our users were infuriated that their data had been lost.